# Is there any automatic fallback from PPP to regular serial console if all else fails?

Tags: serial-console, ppp

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B (8gb RAM) connected to my laptop via TTL-to-USB (UART) cable operating at 115200 baud. The raspi runs Ubuntu 23.04 and the laptop runs Ubuntu 22.10 LTS.

I have a slight tendency to screw up network configurations on my Pi to the point where even rebooting won't fix it. As you can see the serial console is immensely useful to me.

However I would like to set up a PPP connection between my laptop and the Pi. I know how to set it up as there are countless tutorials available to me online, but I'm refraining from doing so until I get a certain question answered:

**If I accidentally screw up all of the Pi's networks and SSH fails to connect over the PPP connection, then how will I be able to access the serial console? Or is it possible to remotely disable PPP from the PC, without any functional network connections to the Pi?** Assume that I have a cron job that enables PPP at startup.

Comment: It's not clear whether you are using the UART (GPIO 14/15) for the PPP connection or not.  Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: @joan Yes, the cable is UART. Updated question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I decided to "take the risk" and set up PPP without knowing the answer to this question.

The answer is now known.

#### *Useful information for future Internet travelers:*

- **If you kill the PPP process on either side then the connection will drop and the regular serial console will become available again.** Good to know information.
- I issued the following command on the server: `sudo pppd noauth` and then immediately disconnected after typing <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> (assuming you are using `sudo cu -l /dev/ttyUSB0 -s 115200` to connect)
- Within 25 seconds of disconnecting I issued this command on my client: `sudo pppd noauth proxyarp /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 192.168.1.2:192.168.1.1 passive local maxfail 0 nocrtscts xonxoff`

Then the server was assigned IP `192.168.1.1` and my client has `192.168.1.2`. Happily ever after.

Comment: You can (and should) select your answer as the correct one; this will help other users by letting them know that this answer resolved the issue.